# How to replace pixel value as a tensorflow operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

I need to replace a pixel value in an image as an operation in the graph. Doing this beforehand is unfortunately not an option as it is part of an optimization process.

As a fix until I come up with a solution, I am simply using `tf.py_func()` but since this operation has to be executed a lot it's very slow and inefficient.

```
# numpy function to perturb a single pixel in an image

def perturb_image(pixel, img):

  # At each pixel's x,y position, assign its rgb value

  x_pos, y_pos, r, g, b = pixel
  rgb = [r,g,b]
  img[x_pos, y_pos] = rgb

  return img

# pixel is a 1D tensor like [x-dim,y-dim,R,G,B]
# image is tensor with shape (x-dim,y-dim,3)

img_perturbed = tf.py_func(perturb_image,[pixel, image], tf.uint8)
```

One way I thought of is using `tf.add(perturbation, image)` where both have the same dimension and perturbation is all zeros except at the pixel location which needs its RGB-values changed to the same value as defined in `pixel` from the above code snippet. Unfortunately, I would need to rewrite a lot of code surrounding this operation which I am trying to avoid.

Can you think of a solution to replace `py_func` with another tensorflow operation using the same inputs?

Any help is much appreciated.